# Why do PRs with git 'squash and merge' option do not appear to merge with master?

Tags: git

GitHub has several options for merging a Pull Request. One is to `Squash and merge`. When this option is chosen, all intermediate commits are squashed before merging. The odd thing is that in the network graph (insights tab), the branch (from which the Pull Request was created) does not appear to merge into master. You see the same thing if you use Sourcetree.

[image]

Instead of selecting, `Squash and merge` if you choose to the `Merge pull request` option, you see the branch merging with master.

[image]

Why does this happen? I would've expected the branch to merge with master after squashing intermediate commits in the `Squash and merge` operation as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graphical tools that are drawing the merge arrow are looking for a 'merge commit'.  Using the 'squash and merge' option on Github does not create a merge commit (it is 'squashed').

More information about the different merge methods on GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/about-merge-methods-on-github/